# Removing javascript from loading in magento website

Tags: javascript, magento

I have a problem, I have 3 javascripts loaded which I don't use. They delay my website for about a second. Can anyone tell me how I can remove those javascripts from being loaded/looked for?
Here under the website log : I'd like to remove jquery, superfish and hoverintent. js but i can't find them!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a quick search on google, specifically look for theme developing and local.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your magento website root and follow this directory path:

```
app/design/fronted/[your-package]/[your-theme]/layout/
```

Open the file `page.xml`

Localize `<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">`

Under this block you will se lots of `<action>` tags wich add javascript files by default. Remove the ones that delay your load.

If you cant find page.xml in this path, try looking for it in the default theme, and if this fails too, fall back to base/default/.